# DLE and Bluetooth Mesh

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-mesh

Is BLE's Data Length Extension (DLE) compatible with Bluetooth Mesh?

I've looked at as many places as I could think, but nowhere does it say that is, nor does it say that it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of this writing BLE mesh does not support Data Length Extension. The main reason for this is that BLE mesh technology is advert-based, and for BLE adverts to have ~251 bytes size you need the BT5 feature BLE Advertising Extensions, and this feature is not defined in the mesh specification.

There are however custom implementations of BLE mesh that take advantage of this feature (e.g. Nordic's Instaburst). However, these don't fully comply with the mesh standard and therefore will not work with all device.

References:-

- [Nordic's Advertiser Extensions (Instaburst)](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.meshsdk.v3.2.0%2Fmd_doc_libraries_instaburst.html)
- [Mesh Networking Specifications](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/mesh-specifications/)

I hope this helps.